# How to Pass data from api into pie chart with angular

Tags: node.js, angular, api, canvas

I would like to pass the output of an API in a piechart canvas with angular but I could not achieve any result, the API is consumed but I have a problem associating it with the piechart (datapoints)
the code just below.

app.component.ts

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmailValidator } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { ApistatService } from './apistat.service';
import * as CanvasJS from './canvasjs.min';
//var CanvasJS = require('./canvasjs.min');
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  elements: any[];
  constructor(
    private apistatService: ApistatService
  ) {  
    this.elements = [];
  }
    ngOnInit() {
    let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        theme: "light2",
        animationEnabled: true,
        exportEnabled: true,
        title:{
            text: "Monthly Expense"
        },
        data: [{
            type: "pie",
            showInLegend: true,
            toolTipContent: "<b>{elements.total}</b>: ${y} (#status)",
            indexLabel: "{name} - #percent%",
            dataPoints: [
                
                { y: 120, name: "Insurance" },
                { y: 300, name: "Traveling" },
                { y: 800, name: "Housing" },
                { y: 150, name: "Education" },
                { y: 150, name: "Shopping"},
                { y: 250, name: "Others" }
            ]
        }]
  });   
  this.apistatService.getData().subscribe((data:any) => {
    if(data.status === 200) {
      console.log(data.response);
      this.elements = data.response;
    }
  })    
    chart.render();
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<div id="chartContainer"  style="height: 370px; width: 100%; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
  

  
</div>
```

> 

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To consume API data in pie chart you should just set data from API to dataPoints array just make sure your API data has same formatting as currently available inside dataPoints array which you are passing in data array while rendering chart, and it will work.

Comment: logical what you said, but I did not have the idea to do it, I looked so much in the documentations but I did not find a solution, I am a beginner in Angular.

Comment: Can you share some link where I can work on your code, maybe that way I can help you?

Comment: give me your discord or email so that I can contact you..

Comment: You can reach out to me at priteshkapuriya@gmail.com